# Update only one parameter of custom Arraylist

Tags: java, android

I have a custom arraylist:

```
ArrayList<Rodada> round = new ArrayList<Rodada>();
```

built with:

```
round.add ((new Rodada(int, int, int, int, int, String, String));
```

I want to refresh the round values, but only the Strings.

if I have 3 indexes (round.add x 3) I want to update only the strings and keep the rest:

```
round [0] = (int, int , int ,int , **new String**, **new String**)

round [1] = (int, int , int ,int , **new String**, **new String**)

round [2] = (int, int , int ,int , **new String**, **new String**)
```

Edit: I had to write this question fast cause I was leaving class.
I have searched before asking, but I have only found cases for on type arrays:

list.set( your_index, your_item );

that was not suitable for, me. Silly question but I could not find it =/

Comment: You need a primer on `ArrayList`, and how it's different from arrays, and on Object Oriented programming as a whole

Comment: To update the fields of an object, the object needs to have a setter method for that field.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get the object at the desired index and update its field.

```
Rodada rodada = round.get(index);
rodada.setDesiredStringField("new value");
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! thanks for the tip!
            for (int index = 0; index < rodada-1;  index++ ){
                Rodada rodada = round.get(index);
                rodada.setTeam1(stringTest);